# Rescuing from failed api calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have an api fetch in my app where once in awhile it'll fail and give out a 500 internal server error which is just fixed with a refresh, but how do I rescue rails from this situation and just have it wait to load the page until the api call is successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this great `retryable` method: [link](http://blog.codefront.net/2008/01/14/retrying-code-blocks-in-ruby-on-exceptions-whatever/).

Note you can customize it with a `sleep` to pause between two requests.